# How to write unit test cases Volley API's?

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-volley

I want to write unit test cases for the Volley API's. So can anyone help me out this?

Comment: can you please explain what you want to do with Volley?

Comment: I just want to write unit test cases for the rest API request-response in android. I have used volley HTTP networking library and I don't found any document related to this.

Answer (score 1):

you can [JSONplaceHolder](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/) for generating fake/Temporary API's for your testing and if you want to setup android volley from scratch [Android Volley](https://www.journaldev.com/17198/android-volley-tutorial) and before using it in your app add dependencies for volley

```
implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'
```

[google official docs for volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley)